# Is there a nice solution to the equation $\Psi(x)=\ln(\pi)$ with a positive real $x$?

Tags: gamma-function, polygamma

I tried to find a nice solution to the following equation:
$$
\Psi(x)=\ln(\pi)
$$
with $x\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ and where $\Psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$.
Is there a nice expression for x satisfying this equation?

Comment: This is not an "algebra-precalculus" problem :)

Comment: You can use $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\Gamma (x)\right)$. But that doesn't help much. I doubt there are analytical solutions to this.

Comment: You can do a Newton-Rapson starting with $\large x = \pi$. That yields $\large x \approx 3.62847320$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no analytic "nice solution".

Approximates of many real solutions can be computed thanks to numerical methods :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+digamma%28x%29%3Dln%28pi%29+for+x
Only one positive real is $x=3.6284732024302883900664192...$

On a formal viewpoint, one could write : $x=\psi^{-1}(ln(\pi))$ but this is of no interest.